# how to match list elements 1-to-1 in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, matching

I have 2 lists in equal number of elements e.g.: `[1,2,3]` and `['a','b','c']`.

I want to merge both of them in the format `[(1,'a')(2,'b')(3,'c')]`. Is it possible? If so, how to do that? I couldn't find a way.

Comment: When in doubt, Hoogle. https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=zip+%3A%3A+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D+-%3E+%5B%28a%2Cb%29%5D

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the `zip` function:

```
> zip [1, 2, 3] ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

For future reference you can use [hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=[a]+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+[%28a%2C+b%29]&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09) to help find functions based on their type signature.

Comment: I was trying to solve from     [(x,y)|x<-..., y<-....]  , But your solution is more elegant and simplier . thnx

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways of doing this.

First, the `zip` function:

```
> zip [1,2,3] "abc"
[(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3, 'c)]
```

And it's pal, the `zipWith` function:

```
> zipWith (,) [1,2,3] "abc"
[(1,'a'), (2,'b'), (3, 'c)]
```

Finally, with the `ParallelListComp` extension*:

```
> [(a,b) | a <- [1,2,3] | b <- "abc"]
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
```

If you're looking for a function in the future, use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3A%3A+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D+-%3E+%5B%28a%2Cb%29%5D), which lets you look for type signatures as well as names.

---

If you really want to, you can define it explicitly:

```
zip' :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip' []     _      = []
zip' _      []     = []
zip' (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs
```

---

*call GHCi with `-XParallelListComp` or add `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XParallelListComp #-}` to your file.